# Wordpress plugin for enhanced WYSIWYG image resizing?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Really, really trying to find a plugin that gives adds functionality to the image-resize functions in Wordpress's WYSIWYG editor. Something where the use of 'Gallery' is not mandatory – just an upload straight from the post editor.

In a post, when an image is linked to from another site, there are less options – unlike when an image is uploaded.

---

• You can resize, but it's 100%, 110%, 120%, 130% ....Instead of thumbnail, large, medium, etc, when you upload.

•These dimension rarely match the dimensions needed.

I know you can type in the W x H in the advanced tab, but my quest to find a better solution is really for the clients using the site.

Any solution / plugin / modification for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this doesn't do exactly what you've said, but could work? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-formatr/

Generally you don't want to give clients too much freedom as it can become confusing. I think what wordpress has is more than satisfactory tbh.

Oh and also, just a note you can alter the thumbnail, medium, large ect sizes in settings>media in the wordpress admin.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.

Thumbnail, medium, large only apply to images that are uploaded from computer, not to images that are 'upload from URL'. That little difference is the problem.

Comment: ahh i see, hmmm... well maybe its a solution thats changed in wordpress 3.0 we can only hope eh?